# How to copy and add element within the same JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Good day, 
I'm working on an Ionic 3 project in which the response http data is in JSON array format like this (from the console):
Array (5)

```
0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"}
1: {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"}
2: {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"}
3: {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"}
4: {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
```

How to (1) copy the "local_TimeStamp" element and (2) append to the same array index so that the new JSON array will look like this:

```
0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", locat_DateTimeStamp: "03-20- 
2018 16:00:00, country: "USA"}
```

I'd tried to loop and copy the local_TimeStamp element and append it like:

```
var newCountryArray = JSON.parse(countryArray);
newCountryArray.forEach( function( item ) {
    var localtime = item.local_TimeStamp;
    var new_obj = {'local_DateTimeStamp': '03182018'+localtime };
    newCountryArray.item.push( new_obj );
});

jsonCountryArray:any = [];
jsonCountryArray = JSON.stringify(newCountryArray);
```

But the above code not working.  Please help!

Thanks.
LHLK

Comment: maybe you want `newCountryArray.item = new_obj ;` ?

Comment: or simply `item.local_TimeStamp = '03182018'+item.local_TimeStamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array= [
{record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
{record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
{record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
{record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
{record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
]

const addLocalDate = item => {

  item.locat_DateTimeStamp = '03182018 '+item.local_TimeStamp;
  return item;
  }

const newArray = array.map(el => addLocalDate(el));
console.log(newArray);
//0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", locat_DateTimeStamp: "03-20- 2018 16:00:00, country: "USA"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new object. Just append the new property to the iterator.

```
var newCountryArray = JSON.parse(countryArray);
newCountryArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var localtime = item.local_TimeStamp;
    item.local_DateTimeStamp = '03182018'+localtime; //<-- add property
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map` and object spread :

```js
var countryArray = JSON.stringify([
    {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
    {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
    {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
    {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
    {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
])

var json = JSON.stringify(
    JSON
        .parse(countryArray)
        .map(entry => ({
            ...entry,
            local_DateTimeStamp: '03182018' + entry.local_TimeStamp
        }))
)

console.log('Json', json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var newCountryArray = JSON.parse(countryArray);
newCountryArray.forEach( function( item ) {
var localtime = item.local_TimeStamp;
items['local_DateTimeStamp'] = '03182018'+localtime
//assigns string to property local_DateTimeStamp on each iteration
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a kinda weird workaround

```js
let arr = [
  {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
  {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
  {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
  {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
  {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
]

let newArr = Array(arr.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => Object.assign({}, arr[i], { local_DateTimeStamp: '03182018 '+arr[i].local_TimeStamp }));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const initialCountryArray = [ 
  {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
  {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
  {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
  {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
  {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"} 
];

const newCountryArray = initialCountryArray.map(country => {
  return { ...country, 'local_DateTimeStamp': '03182018'+country.local_TimeStamp};
});

console.log(newCountryArray);
```

Comment: you can avoid return: .map(country => ({...country, 'local_DateTimeStamp': '03182018'+country.local_TimeStamp}));